# Add extra field when admin create user

Tags: admin, users

I have created extra field that user can edit on their 'Your Profile' page. The extra field also available on WordPress register page. What I want to ask is, how to add the field to User > Add new page ? So, when admin creates a user, admin also input the user's extra field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no hooks on that page (User > Add new page) other then `user_new_form_tag` its not possible to add new fields unless you hack the core file `wp-admin/user-new.php` .

You could try adding that extra field by adding in in JQuery and processing it when the `$_post['action'] == 'adduser'` but that wont be very good practice.

Comment: I want to avoid hacking the core, so maybe I will choose the jQuery solution. It is okay if it's not very good practice, As long as it works :D, thanks for the solution Bainternet

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Personally, I would say the jQuery approach is better practice than hacking core. Once you have modified core, upgrading becomes a chore.

Comment: @Bainternet: Where do some one put that `$_post['action'] == 'adduser'` and How can get the last inserted wordpress user's id to update the user extra field in custom table. You should expend your answer.

Comment: I think the action now is "createuser". At least I've got this while debugging the admin user creation process.

Answer (score 1):

This is older question but there is this now.. end of form though (only).

WP Version 4.3.0 - File "./wp-admin/user-new.php" - Line 330

```
/**
 * Fires at the end of the new user form.
 *
 * Passes a contextual string to make both types of new user forms
 * uniquely targetable. Contexts are 'add-existing-user' (Multisite),
 * and 'add-new-user' (single site and network admin).
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 *
 * @param string $type A contextual string specifying which type of new user form the hook follows.
 */
do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-existing-user' );
```

Short example:

```
add_action('user_new_form', 'addmycustomfield');
function addmycustomfield() {
?>
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
<th scope="row">My test field:</th>
<td><input type="text" size="32" name="testfield" value="<?php echo get_option('madeup_wp_option'); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table> 
<?php
}
```

This will place a field on end of add user form.
How to save custom user meta data/etc from registration/add user/profile edit/etc is beyond scope of the question and has been answered many times previously. See comments as well.

Comment: Would you please expand upon this answer?

Comment: He was looking for action hooks on user add form. This seems to be a new one since first answers were posted above. A code example that expands on this hook is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23067428/503621

Comment: More specifically: this hook allows you to add a field to page he requested. Which was the question..

Comment: I understand but simply pasting code is only helpful to people with experience enough to understand the code.

Comment: Added some code to answer.. also link above in comments is better example. Thanks for input..

Comment: The easiest solution of all time. thanks a ton, man.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this through a rather fragile hack.  It uses the output buffer to insert the new field.  Thankfully there's a nice hook to save the field.

```
// FRAGILE!  This rewrites code directly in the buffer, upgrading WP may break this
function wpse18772_add_fields( $buffer ) {
  $input_html = '<input type="text" name="your-new-field" id="your-new-field">';

  // will insert a new field after "role"
  $buffer = preg_replace( '~<label\s+for="role">(.*?)</tr>~ims', '<label for="role">$1</tr><tr class="form-field"><th>My New Field</th><td>' . $input_html . '</td></tr>', $buffer );

  return $buffer;
}

function wpse18772_buffer_start() { ob_start("wpse18772_add_fields");  }
function wpse18772_buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse18772_buffer_start', 10, 1);
add_action('admin_footer', 'wpse18772_buffer_end', 10, 1);

function wpse18772_save_fields($user_id) {
  if($_POST['action'] != "adduser" && $_POST['action'] != "createuser") return;

  if(!empty($_POST['your-new-field'])) {
    // save field to meta, or do whatever you want to here
  }
}
add_action('user_register', 'wpse18772_save_fields');
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74332/show-biographical-info-while-creating-new-user/74382#74382). There are no hooks, but you can do it with jQuery. Simply add your html markup with jQuery and it will be done.