# How to append new form elements in "Add New" form of Users in Wordpress admin panel?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms, filters, actions

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and I want to append some extra form fields in add new form of Users section inside admin panel without editing core files. Can somebody help me in achieving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding fields to the "Add New User" screen in the dashboard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23813/adding-fields-to-the-add-new-user-screen-in-the-dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

As of WordPress 3.0.0 this action is available at the top of the new user form:

`user_new_form_tag`

As of WordPress 3.7.0 this action is called at the end of the form (right before submit button):

`user_new_form`

You will however need to intercept when clicking submit to save any specific user information to the user's meta

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of tutorials for doing this, take a look here for example :
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

You can use following hooks : `show_user_profile`, `edit_user_profile`, `personal_options_update`, `edit_user_profile_update` ...

EDIT : But it will not add fields on the "New User" form since there is no hook for that :
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-admin/user-new.php

But you can :

- try to add needed fields using javascript, and use `user_register` hook to add user meta data in db.
- Or build your own form.

Comment: I want to add form fields on new user registration form i.e on "add new" page of users section. The link only shows how to add such functionality on "**edit-user**" and "**your profile**" page of users section.

Comment: Sorry, answer updated.

Comment: please don't answer just because you have to. read the question properly.

Comment: Please don't comment if you don't have any useful information to give.

Comment: That's the point of this site, to ask, to answer. Sometimes we make mistakes. That's what down-voting is for, in cases where bad advice/incorrect answers are given, assuming the user doesn't make the effort to correct his/her answer. But without **genuine** contributions from users this resource doesn't exist. Point in case, if Soju didn't answer this question, it'd still be unanswered. Now who does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter to add your fields:

```
apply_filters( 'show_password_fields', true );
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', 'yourfunction', 10, 1 );
function yourfunction( $return ) {
    ?><tr>
        <th><label for="gender">Gender</label></th>
        <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="w4p_user_gender" value="male" class="regular-radio" />Male</label>
            <label style="margin-left:10px"><input type="radio" name="w4p_user_gender" value="female" class="regular-radio" />Female</label><br/>
            <span class="description">Please select your Gender.</span>
        </td>
    </tr><?php
    return $return;
}
```

I don't know if it's a good idea or not, but it works for me. :)

Comment: But, does this works for custom user meta? As far as I tested, only for default user meta... Are you doing something [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18777/12615)?